# Is there a way to call DbContext.Translate on a collection of results without explicity passing in there generic types?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a stored procedure that I am calling through an entity framework that returns multiple results. I have been using the DbContext.Translate method to map these results back to entities like this:

```
List<T1> result1 = ObjectContext.Translate<T1>(reader).ToList();
reader.NextResult();

List<T2> result2 = ObjectContext.Translate<T2>(reader).ToList();
reader.NextResult();

List<T3> result3 = ObjectContext.Translate<T3>(reader).ToList();
reader.NextResult();
```

This works great, but now I have a procedure that is returning over 20 results. I want to be able to map the results generically without creating 20 overloads of my method (since I foresee more stored procedures returning 2-20 result set in the future).

Is there some way that I could do this mapping in a loop without having many method overloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way that I could do this mapping in a loop without
>   having many method overloads?

I would say, no.

I think what you have described already is the best way of doing this, considering you *have* to tell the `ObjectContext` what types it's dealing with.

You could create a set of generic functions (similar to `Func<T>` and `Action<T>`) with multiple overloads containing an increasing number of generic parameters.

For example, the first two implementations could look like the following:

```
public static Tuple<List<T1>> GetSprocResults<T1>
    (DataTableReader reader, ObjectContext objectContext)
{
    var t1 = objectContext.Translate<T1>(reader).ToList();

    return new Tuple<List<T1>>(t1);
}

public static Tuple<List<T1>, List<T2>> GetSprocResults<T1, T2>
    (DataTableReader reader, ObjectContext objectContext)
{
    var t1 = objectContext.Translate<T1>(reader).ToList();
    reader.NextResult();

    var t2 = objectContext.Translate<T2>(reader).ToList();

    return new Tuple<List<T1>, List<T2>>(t1, t2);
}
```

Example usage:

```
        var result = GetSprocResults<DateTime, int>(reader, objectContext);

        var datesCount = result.Item1.Count;
        var intCount = result.Item2.Count;
```

I don't think there is a problem with having multiple overloads if it makes sense in the context of your code to re-factor this functionality to a set of methods.

Comment: This is what the code is already doing. However, since the end result is a lot of duplicate code, I was hoping their was a way to make it more generic. For instance, if I could pass in a collection of return types somehow and iterate over them.